# Train Object Detection Module Using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I am executing the following command to train model using tenserflow, I got below errors.

**Command** :

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

**Errors** :

```
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "legacy/train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
  File "D:\tf1.12\model\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import decoder_builder
  File "D:\tf1.12\model\research\object_detection\builders\decoder_builder.py", line 25, in <module>
    from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
  File "D:\tf1.12\model\research\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tf_slim import tfexample_decoder as slim_example_decoder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'
```

So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably *tf-slim* package is not installed in your python environment. Try running below command in the conda prompt

```
pip install tf-slim
```